# How to link a Product Backlog from one project to another project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I come to this forum to ask you a practical and technical question.

We use `Azure DevOps`
Here is the architecture of the Projects

```
Organization/*emphasized text*
./Projet1
./Projet2
./Projet3
```

We have Product Backlogs in each Project

My question is simple: is it possible to link the product backlog from `Project3 to Project1` without making a copy of the Product `baclog` of the `project1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can link work item between projects. As example:

1. You can add the child line to an existing work item of another project with the same process:

[image]

2. Then you`ll see the note that that work item does bellow to current project or team:

[image]

However, you may consider to use one team project to that purpose and separate your internal projects by area path: [Portfolio management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/portfolio-management?view=azure-devops), [Implement Scaled Agile Framework® to support epics, release trains, and multiple backlogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/scaled-agile-framework?view=azure-devops)